# windowbuttondown can not read updated image

Tags: image, matlab, user-interface

recently I build a interface in MATLAB, and my goal is to fix the original cell segmentation results by changing the value of the pixels. I mostly depend on three functions to do the job: WindowButtonDown WindowButtonMotion WindowButtonUp, but it seems it can only implement once, that is to say, when I click the button the second time, it just ignores the updated Img when I finish adding one cell and uses the original version of the image. I don't know why because I clearly state at the end of my WindowButtonMotion Function: handles.Img = Img.

here is part of my code:

```
function figure2_WindowButtonDownFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
global Mflag x0 y0 x y PaintFlag Eflag value m;

......
Img=handles.Img;
m=max(Img(:));

Mflag = 1;
......
guidata(hObject, handles);

function figure2_WindowButtonMotionFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
global Mflag x0 y0 x y PaintFlag Eflag value m;

......

if Mflag
 Img=handles.Img;
 .....
 if PaintFlag
    .....
    if temp1==get(handles.Add,'Max')&&temp2==get(handles.Fix,'Min')

       Color = handles.cmap(m+1,:);
       Img(xx,yy)=m+1;      
       handles.Img=Img;%when I set keyboard after this I found the updated image had been stored in handles.
    elseif temp1==get(handles.Add,'Min')&&temp2==get(handles.Fix,'Max')

       Color = handles.cmap(value,:);
       Img(xx,yy)=value;
       handles.Img=Img;
    end
  end
    ......
end
guidata(hObject, handles);

function figure2_WindowButtonUpFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
global Mflag;
Mflag = 0;
guidata(hObject, handles);
```

I just can't figure out why the WindowButtonDown Function can't read the updated Img in WindowButtonMotion, I need the m to increase gradually when I add new cells. But it just keep read the original one. I wonder why and how can I fix this?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Callbacks behave like every other function in MATLAB, they operate on variables within the scope of the function only. The `handles` structure you're operating on is a copy local to the function and is not passed back to the rest of the GUI. I would recommend using [`guidata`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/guidata.html) or [`setappdata`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setappdata.html)/[`getappdata`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getappdata.html) instead.

Comment: I see you are using many global variables - maybe consider writing the gui as an object? The object would have Img property and callback methods that access it. If you choose to stick with functions - use setappdata as recommended above. Mathwork claims it is better (faster) for things other than handles to gui elements.